# Error 1093 no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Segue o meu código em MySQL:

```
create schema if not exists Faculdade;

use faculdade;

create table if not exists Alunos
(
    RA integer UNSIGNED not null,
    senha varchar(15) not null,
    nome varchar(100) not null,
    faltas integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (RA)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

create table if not exists Materias
(
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    nome varchar(50) not null,
    nota1 float,
    nota2 float,
    medias float, 
    substitutiva float,
    RA integer UNSIGNED not null,
    primary key(id,RA)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;


ALTER TABLE `Materias` ADD CONSTRAINT `RA` FOREIGN KEY ( `RA` ) REFERENCES `Alunos` ( `RA` ) ;

drop database faculdade;

describe Alunos;

describe Materias;

insert into Alunos values(201500983,'12345','Marcos Paes Leme',0);
insert into Alunos values(201500984,'54321','Dionizio',0);
insert into Alunos values(201500985,'1357','Paulo José',0);
insert into Alunos values(201500986,'2468','Robervau',0);

select * from Alunos;

insert into Materias values(1,'Alged',6.0,7.0,(select sum(nota1+nota2)/2 from Materias where RA = 201500984),0.0,(select RA from Alunos where RA=201500984));
insert into Materias values(1,'Alged',6.0,7.0,(select sum(nota1+nota2)/2 from Materias where RA = 201500984),0.0,(select RA from Alunos where RA=201500984));
select * from Materias;
```

Quando tento executar o `insert` na minha tabela `materias` da o seguinte erro:

> you can't specify target table for update in from clause mysql.

Quando executo separadamente o comando: `select sum(nota1+nota2) from Materias where RA = 201500984` ele executa.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se tem outros problemas mas tem um erro claro e outras duas coisas esquisitas que acabam provocando o erro reportado.

A chave primária é `ID + RA`. Um problema ocorre quando está se tentando inserir duas linhas com a mesma chave primária. Na verdade nem chegou vê-lo porque outro problema acontece antes.

A expressão `(select RA from Alunos where RA=201500984)` não faz o menor sentido, afinal o resultado da coluna `RA` certamente será `201500984`.

Isso também não faz sentido: `select sum(nota1+nota2)/2 from Materias where RA = 201500984`. Vai pegar uma coisa que está inserindo agora? Não vai funcionar.

Algo assim funcionaria:

```
insert into Materias values(1, 'Alged', 6.0, 7.0, (nota1 + nota2) / 2, 0.0, 201500984);
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20a1a/1). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/Grades.sql).

Obviamente não sei se é a intenção. A segunda linha já teria que ser outro RA. Espero que entenda porque não está nomeando as colunas. Esse caso funciona, mas pode trazer complicações de manutenção.

Answer (score 1):

Modifique a query de inserção, fazendo um `INSERT` com `SELECT`, da seguinte forma:

```
insert into Materias
(select 1,'Alged',6.0,7.0,(select sum(nota1+nota2)/2 from Materias where RA = 201500984),0.0,(select RA from Alunos where RA=201500984));
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado @Lucas tom, funcionou

Comment: Não esquece de marcar a resposta como a melhor, isso ajuda nossos amiguinhos e também me ajuda.